# Downloadable Database to derive time zone from lat long coordinates

Tags: database, timezone, location, latitude-longitude

I found a lot of libraries/APIs providing time zone information from lat long information. But, what I want is database that can be loaded on our servers which then can be used by our applications.

Comment: @LennartRegebro No, it is not a duplicate of that question. This question clearly mentions that it seeks a downloadable database.

Comment: That question has answer that includes several downloadable databases.